# Creating spheres In Matlab that change surface color depending on data

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure, geometry-surface

I am trying to create a series of randomly distributed spheres in Matlab, three will be three sub-sets. I would like each subset to have a different color. I am using a structure because each sphere will also have different properties associated with it. I tried using colormap, and set(...'FaceColor'..) but am having some difficulty. Please Help.

```
for n = 1:100
    Bslice.cell(n).index = n; 
    Bslice.cell(n).type = 'Tyep1'; % Type2, Type3
    Bslice.cell(n).location = round(rand(1, 3)*10);
end 

%%
[x,y,z] = sphere;

for n = 1:10
    hold on 
    grid on
    surfl(x-Bslice.cell(n).location(1), y-Bslice.cell(n).location(2), z-Bslice.cell(n).location(3)); 
    shading interp
    % colormap(hot(100))
end
```

Comment: Is another way to phrase your question- how can I make three 3D clusters?

Answer (score 1):

Create a matrix `c` corresponding to the color of each point on the sphere. Then,

```
[x y z] = sphere;
surf(x,y,z,c);
```

More documentation on [`surf` here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html).